# how to make a control in listTile with flutter

Tags: list, flutter

how to make a control in a lisTile with flutter. i get  datas from json and display them in a listTile,. but i want to make a if control to show a button.

```
if(data[position]['value'] == 0){
       sho raised button;
}else{
    don't show it;

}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can add a button on the trailing edge of the tile, using the `trailing` property of `ListTile`.

For example, here we add an `IconButton` :

```
Widget _ = ListView.builder(
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return ListTile(
          title: Text("Row $index"),
          trailing: (data[position]['value'] == 0)
              ? IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.alarm), onPressed: () {})
              : null);
    });
```